# How to set a viewScope variable in Java

Tags: java, xpages

In my XPages application I want to steer the bahaviour of an XPage when performing calculations in the back-end in java.

I would like to control the behaviour by setting viewScope variables to calculate the rendered property of some controls.

Can someone guide me how I can achieve this? Google has not been my friend so far...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ExtLibUtil.getViewScope().put("variableKey", "variableValue");
```

Comment: @Malin, and you also have ExtLibUtil.getRequestScope(), ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope() and ExtLibUtil.getApplicationScope()

Comment: Also, there's `ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable()`. Since FP8, it includes Jesse's Gallagher's pull request to allow you to just pass the variable name (e.g. `ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable("requestScope")`), before you need to pass `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` as the second parameter. This becomes very powerful when including OpenNTF Domino API, with scopes like serverScope, userScope and identityScope (see http://paulswithers.me.uk/odaDemoApp/, "XPages Variables" sub page)

Answer (score 2):

Malin,

I suggest you use managed beans as Howard recommends. It is very convenient when you work with Java in XPages.

**1. Create a bean**

It's just an ordinary java bean - with a constructor without arguments. For example:

```
public class ExporterBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int numberOfDocs = 1L;

    public ExporterBean() {
        System.out.println("Instantiating ExporterBean");
    }

    public int getNumberOfDocs() {
        return numberOfDocs;
    }

    public void setNumberOfDocs(int numberOfDocs) {
        this.numberOfDocs = numberOfDocs;
    }
}
```

Please note that you should implement Serializable for all your beans. View-scope will force you to do so - but not the others (but it can bite you later depending on whether you keep beans in memory or serialize them to disk)

**2. Define it as a managed bean**

You do that in the file *faces-config.xml* under *Application Configuration* in the navigation of Domino Designer. You need to add something like:

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Exporter</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>dk.myapp.bean.ExporterBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

The scope can be: **request**, **view**, **session**, or **application**. Once you have done that then you can just reference the bean directly in your XPage using the name you specified in faces-config.xml.

In my example it could be:

```
<xp:text escape="false" value="#{Exporter.numberOfDocs}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

/John

Answer (score 1):

Why not just just managed bean properties for that? In my apps I just about never use scoped variables any more.

Comment: This is also the way I do it... ;-)